# Testing checklist for a win app that will be working on win 7

Tags: windows

We are in process of preparing a testing checklist to make sure that our newly developed windows app (.NET 3.5, WPF) is going to be worked well on windows 7 in all environments.

Since our app is accessing WMI,USB devices(we have a USB blocker),windows power plans since we have power saving utility.

Because of that, we prepared a small checklist to make sure that our app will works well even if users change some windows settings.
Here is what we currently have:

1. Testing with 64 and 32bit OS.
2. Testing with OS that is not installed on C:\ drive.
3. Trying with windows running with/without domain.
4. Turning off windows installer service and making sure that our app is going to turn it on during installation.
5. Checking WMI service before accessing WMI.
6. Testing on laptop/Desktop machines.

We still need more test cases to cover more scenarios.
So if you have any more suggestions, that would help a lot.

Thank you!